# Circular shift of a string element

Tags: python, numpy

Basically I have converted an integer into binary representation and after that it is stored in string format.

I want to circularly rotate the number.

How should I proceed?

I have used `np.roll()` but it is not working.

Comment: I need some more information. Can you edit your question to post with your code? How about reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)?

Answer (score 2):

You can just create a new string as follows to circularly shift it

```
bin_str = bin_str[-1] + bin_str[:-1]
```

If thats of no good, you can use `collections.deque` (which has a `rotate` method) to have circular shift effect

```
from collections import deque
bin_str = "{0:b}".format(10)
print (bin_str)
1010

d = deque(bin_str, maxlen=len(bin_str))
print (d)
# deque(['1', '0', '1', '0'], maxlen=4)

d.rotate()
print (d)
# deque(['0', '1', '0', '1'], maxlen=4)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using negative shift 
 for example like this 
print(np.roll(a, -3))

Comment: "I have used np.roll() but it is not working." I'm not sure what this answer adds.